# Can't upload captured picture from android device to RoR webapp using form

Tags: android, html, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, web-applications

**Edit: Problem solved, I posted a comment about it.**

Recently I have been trying to implement functionality of uploading a picture to my RoR web application(just basics, storing pictures locally under app/public/uploads). 
I started off with code from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files 
and everything seems to be working fine except when I upload a picture I have just taken with my mobile phone. Recording a video and uploading it immediately works just fine. Uploading a picture stored anywhere in phone works fine.

This is my html code:

```
<div align="center">
    <%= form_tag({controller: :static_pages, action: :upload}, multipart: true) do %>
        <%= file_field_tag 'picture' %>
        <%= submit_tag "Upload picture"%>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Form creates a simple button("Browse") and text next to it, which says "No file selected" or name of the file I selected.

And this is my controller action:

```
def upload

  if params[:picture].nil?
    redirect_to '/static_pages/error'
    return
  end

  uploaded_io = params[:picture]

  if File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
    end
  end

end
```

And finally routing:

```
 match 'static_pages/upload', to: 'static_pages#upload', via: 'post'
```

I have done some debugging and it seems like the controller action is not being called in this case - taking a picture with camera and uploading it right away. The file name is next to the "Browse" button every time, even if I take it with camera, so I guess the photo is there somewhere, but somehow static_pages#upload is not called.
If I select the picture I have just taken from file, it uploads without any problems.
What am I doing wrong?

I am a RoR and HTML beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it is some weird Chrome bug. Today I tested it on multiple devices and weirdly only my phone acts this way. I had no idea this could be browser related problem.
Anyway, hopefully this post will help someone, obviously I should have thought of trying to test my app on multiple browsers.